# Why aren't stratum sample sizes maintained using rsample bootstraps?

Tags: r

*[After seeing **joran**'s comment below about the `make_strata()` function, I filed an [issue](http://github.com/tidymodels/rsample/issues/86) with **rsample** on Github.]*

I'm trying to take stratified bootstrap samples from a data frame.  I want separate bootstrap samples to be taken within each stratum, so that the resulting bootstrap sample has the same number of observations in each stratum as the original data frame.  However, that does not always happen when using the `bootstraps()` function of the **rsample** package.  When I run this code:

```
library(rsample)

mydf <- data.frame(A=1:58, B=rep(1:4, c(6, 6, 23, 23)))
lboots <- bootstraps(mydf, times=3, strata="B")$splits
lbootsdf <- lapply(lboots, as.data.frame)

with(mydf, table(B))
lapply(lbootsdf, function(df) table(df$B))
```

These are the results I get:

```
B
 1  2  3  4 
 6  6 23 23 


$`1`
 1  2  3  4 
10  5 20 23 

$`2`
 1  2  3  4 
 3  8 24 23 

$`3`
 1  2  3  4 
 4  5 24 25
```

I was expecting to see 6 1's, 6 2's, 23 3's, and 23 4's in each of the three bootstrap samples.

How can I take the type of stratified bootstrap sample that I want?

Comment: Because it's random?

Comment: @42- I'm pretty sure they are expecting a stratified bootstrap sample to generate a bootstrap sample _within_ each unique value in B, so that each of the three resamples should be balanced. That's sort of what I would expect, too.

Comment: After a little digging, it seems that the function `make_strata` by default pools strata below 15% of the total, and there is currently no way to adjust that parameter from the calling functions, like `boostraps()`. This package is still pretty early in development, I would probably make a note of this on github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't use `rsample::bootstraps` but instead constructs the bootstrap samples explicitly.

```
library("dplyr")

splits <- mydf %>%
  crossing(id = seq(2)) %>%
  group_by(id, B) %>%
  sample_n(n(), replace = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()
```

`lboots$splits[[id]]$data` are copies of the original data.

Comment: This works well.  Great use of crossing() to get multiple bootstrap samples.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the "B" component of the lboots object (made without subsetting splits, I see consistency on the sampling faction.

BUT: that apparently not the designed out as joran points out. Appears this is a package in early development, since the documentation is not in sync with the code.:

```
maintainer("rsample") 
[1] "Max Kuhn <max@rstudio.com>"

 lboots <- bootstraps(mydf, times=3, strata="B")
 str(lboots)
 table(lboots$splits[['1']]$data$B)

 1  2  3  4 
 6  6 23 23 
> table(lboots$splits[['2']]$data$B)

 1  2  3  4 
 6  6 23 23 
> table(lboots$splits[['3']]$data$B)

 1  2  3  4 
 6  6 23 23
```

Comment: You're looking at copies of the original data, I think. The `lboots` objects are lists, where the `data` element is the _original_ data, and `in_id` is the indexes of the selected rows.

Comment: I confess I'm a little mystified at the upvotes and acceptance. This answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: OK your right.  `identical( lboots$splits[['3']]$data ,lboots$splits[['2']]$data) 
[1] TRUE` Tried to delete but acceptance prevents deletion.

Comment: The help page suggests to me that the samples are supposed to retain their origianl proportions by strata: "The strata argument is based on a similar argument in the random forest package were the bootstrap samples are conducted within the stratification variable. The can help ensure that the number of data points in the bootstrap sample is equivalent to the proportions in the original data set." Maybe it's a bug. Whether it's a bug in code or docs is unclear: `maintainer("rsample")
[1] "Max Kuhn <max@rstudio.com>"`

Comment: Yes, see my comment under the question. I think the package just has some "features" whose development is out of sync of unfinished. The problem comes from a fairly strange implementation in the function `make_strata` and no way to alter that functions default settings from `bootstraps()`.

Comment: Well, I'm sure Jean knows how to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look as if you're doing a bootstrap sample because you're not estimating the sampling distribution of a statistic. What it seems to me that you're trying to do is a stratified sample (i.e. instead of a simple random sample) of the data stored in `mydf$A` using `mydf$B` as the strata.

The package `dplyr` has a function that is purpose-built for this scenario, `sample_frac`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf <- data.frame(A=1:58, B=rep(1:4, c(6, 6, 23, 23)))
data_grouped_by_stratum <- mydf %>% group_by(mydf$B)
data_sampled_by_stratum <- data_grouped_by_stratum %>% sample_frac(size=1, replace=T)
# Now, a bit of cleanup on the resulting tibble object
df_of_data_sampled_by_stratum <- data_sampled_by_stratum %>% dplyr::ungroup %>% dplyr::select(-`mydf$B`) %>% as.data.frame
```

In the call to `sample_frac`, `size=1` means that the fraction of the rows to sample within each group is 1; i.e. 100% of the group's rows.

Comment: Helpful pointer to use of sample_frac().  Could use this in combination with crossing() to get multiple bootstrap samples as in accepted answer from dipetkov.  [I'm just interested in the sample at this point, will apply some functions to the sample later.]